# Access-class in denies telnet under specific configuration

Tags: acl

So I created an Access-list to permit telnet from a specific subnet. Here is the network diagram.

[image: Network Permit Telnet vty lines R4]

I originally tried permitting the subnet 10.1.1.0 /24  to access the R4 vty lines 0 4.  It was a simple statement:

```
Access-list extended 120 permit tcp 10.1.1.0 0.0.0.255 host 172.16.0.2 eq 23
```

I applied it to the 0 4 vty lines on R4 inbound using `access-class 120 in`

The connection was refused by R4 and it definitely was only when the access-class 120 in was applied to the lines.  If I removed it I was immediately prompted for local login and enable password and given access.

I tried several different combinations until I tried this one and got access:

```
access-list 120 permit tcp 10.1.1.0 0.0.0.255 any eq telnet

Vty settings are the same for both:
!
line vty 0 4
 access-class 120 in
 login local
 transport input telnet
 privilege level 15
```

!

The only difference is the destination of "any" vs a specific ip address of a serial port 172.16.0.2 0.0.0.0

But that difference seems to make all the difference.

Any thoughts on why this is the case, it is a simulation in Packet Tracer and I know that can be problematic under certain conditions.

Comment: It may be a "feature" of packet tracer, but I have seen similar "oddities" on real routers, depending on the IOS version.  ACLs on VTY lines are processed differently than on interfaces.

Comment: Yeah I definitely didn't see a real difference other than a single IP versus any.  I will definitely wait though to see if anyone has figured this out or can clarify it before I accept that as the reason, you make me feel a little better though I thought perhaps I was missing something right in front of me.

Comment: Could it be that denying telnet to other R4 interfaces is pointless because if I can telnet to one interface then it is technically the same thing as telnetting to another interface on the same router.  Makes no sense to permit telnet to one and not the others?  But that would imply some kind of intelligence wouldn't it?  When in reality routers only do what we ask them to do, I don't know grasping at this point

Comment: That's as good a reason as any.  But sometimes there is no reason behind it and it's simply, "that's the way the programmer wrote it."